# ConstraintLayout-Params are ignored

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

i want to create an calendar Day-View like the one Google has.
For that i want to create dynamically the timelines. Thats the way i do it right now:

```
TextView nextTime = new TextView(this);
View nextView = new View(this);
View nextLine = new View(this);

ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lineParams = new 
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams timeParams = new 
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams viewParams = new 
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

viewParams.topToBottom = firstView.getId();
viewParams.leftToLeft = firstView.getId();
viewParams.height = Utils.changeDPItoPX(26, displayMetrics);
viewParams.width = Utils.changeDPItoPX(0, displayMetrics);
viewParams.setMargins(0, Utils.changeDPItoPX(16, displayMetrics),0,0);
nextView.setLayoutParams(viewParams);
constraintLayout.addView(nextView);

timeParams.topToTop = nextView.getId();
timeParams.bottomToBottom = nextView.getId();
timeParams.leftToLeft = nextView.getId();
timeParams.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
timeParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
timeParams.setMargins(Utils.changeDPItoPX(16, displayMetrics), 0,0,0);
nextTime.setLayoutParams(timeParams);
constraintLayout.addView(nextTime);

lineParams.height = Utils.changeDPItoPX(2, displayMetrics);
lineParams.bottomToBottom = nextTime.getId();
lineParams.endToEnd = nextView.getId();
lineParams.startToEnd = nextTime.getId();
lineParams.topToTop = nextTime.getId();
lineParams.setMargins(Utils.changeDPItoPX(8, displayMetrics), 0, 
Utils.changeDPItoPX(8, displayMetrics), 0);
lineParams.width = Utils.changeDPItoPX(0, displayMetrics);
nextLine.setLayoutParams(lineParams);
constraintLayout.addView(nextLine);
```

In my layout xml for the activity i already have the first timestamp. So this code should add the next one. And it looks like this:

|  00:00 --------------------------  |

|  01:--0--0 -----------------------|

The timeLine is over my time and it also goes to end of the screen.
But it should look like the timeStamp above.

What am i doing wrong? Why does it ignore the constraints?

Answer (score 0):

Use ConstraintSet instead of Layout params for adding the views to your ConstraintLayout.

You can refer the following link for the understanding how to use ConstraintSet

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html

Comment: Ok i thought i get it. But why is this now not working?

    constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainframe);
    constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);

    View nextView = new View(this);
constraintSet.connect(nextView.getId(),ConstraintSet.TOP, firstView.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, Utils.changeDPItoPX(20, displayMetrics));
constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
constraintLayout.addView(nextView);

it doesnt care about the margin i set. And its on top of my firstView

Comment: As per the connect method it will accept following parameters

connect(int startID, int startSide, int endID, int endSide, int margin);

can you please check that your constraint is proper according to that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it figured out. So what you basically have to do when you want to add a view dynamically and then constraint it to other views is this:

#### First get your constraint layout in which you for example already have a view

```
constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainframe);
View firstView = findViewById(R.id.firstView);
```

#### Create new view you want to add

```
View nextView = new View(this);
nextView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
```

#### Now add the view to your constraint layout

```
constraintLayout.addView(nextView);
```

#### For the last step you clone your constraint layout then add the constraints you want to add and apply them to your constraint layout

```
constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
constraintSet.connect(nextView.getId(),ConstraintSet.TOP, 
firstView.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 16);
constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

I hope i can help with that if someone has the same problem.